# Where is the tutorial mentioned in the Hibernate reference documentation?

Tags: hibernate

I'm just starting to learn Hibernate ORM, and the very first paragraph of chapter 1 of the reference documentation says:

> All code is contained in the `tutorials/web` directory of the
>   project source.

It then goes on to say:

> The distribution contains another example application under the
>   `tutorial/eg` project source directory.

So I cloned the project source from Github by doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm.git
```

However, the `tutorials` directory does not contain a `web` subdirectory, and there is no `tutorial` directory at all! One paragraph in and I'm already finding inconsistencies!

Clearly their documentation is out of sync with their distribution (not a good sign), but does anyone know where I can get these (presumably old) tutorials so I can follow along with their (presumably outdated) documentation?

I'd also just like to say: c'mon Hibernate!

Comment: This might be better suited for the JBOSS issue tracker. I'd consider looking at the tutorials they *do* have and seeing whether they match the snippets in the reference docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in the 3.5 release: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/3.5/tutorials  Perhaps they removed it in 3.6.